# React anti pattern?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, static

Is the following an anti pattern in React? I like the pattern because it gives me context in static functions when a component has been instantiated. Then later I can import the class and call a static method to modify state. Or can this be done in a better way?

```js
// componentA.js

function bleedContext() {
  ComponentA.staticMethod = ComponentA.staticMethod.bind(this)
}

export default class ComponentA {
  static staticMethod() {
    this.setState({foo: 'bar'})
  }
  
  constructor() {
    this.state = {}
    bleedContext.call(this)
  }
  
  render() {
    return (
      ...
    )
  }
}

// componentB.js

import ComponentA from 'path/to/componentA'

export default class ComponentB {  
  handleClick() {
    ComponentA.staticMethod()
  }
  
  render() {
    return (
      <button onClick={this.handleClick} />
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: I can definitely see some cases where that would cause problems. What is your goal, and have you tried using props to do it or, failing that, a ref?

Comment: Forgetting about React for a second, a static method that references `this` seems odd. Static methods are for the entire class, but this method knows about a particular instance?

Comment: My current use case is a modal that instantiates before most of the other components and only 1 time. I would like to be able to update the state of the modal component from a lot of different components later on.

Comment: @FrankModica - jep these statics knows about the instance. I know that statics are used as helper functions typically, that know nothing abount one particular instance.

Comment: This has nothing to do with React, but yes it is a horrible antipattern. You are essentially creating a global singleton instance, hidden as the class itself. If you insist on using singletons, at least make it so that it become obvious what you are doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is clearly an antipattern and possibly a mistake, depending on conditions. Static class method shouldn't operate with class instance. `staticMethod` is bound to specific component instance and uses `setState`, this could be only justified a class is a singleton (though a singleton is often an antipattern, too). This will result in bugs and memory leaks if more than one class instance is expected, and every React component is expected to have more than one instance, at least for testing.

A proper way for two independent components to interact with each other in React is to have a common parent component that provides this interaction, e.g.:

```
class ModalContainer extends Component {
  modalRef = React.createRef();

  render() {
    return <>
      <Modal ref={this.modalRef} />
      <SomeComponentThatUsesModal modalRef={this.modalRef} />
    </>;
  }
}
```

The problem with example above is that this will require to pass `modalRef` prop deeply if `<SomeComponentThatUsesModal>` is nested.

This problem is solved with React context or other third-party global state solutions like Redux.

This can be done with React 16.3 context API, considering that `Modal` class instance has `open` method:

```
const ModalContext = React.createContext();

function getModal(modalRef) {
  return {
    open: data => modalRef.current.open(data);
    close: () => modalRef.current.close();
  }
}

class ModalContainer extends Component {
  modalRef = React.createRef();

  render() {
    return <>
      <Modal ref={this.modalRef} />
      <ModalContext.Provider value={getModal(this.modalRef)}>
        {this.props.children}
      </ModalContext.Provider>
    </>;
  }
}
```

Then for any deeply nested component modal object with `open` and close methods will be available via context:

```
const SomeComponentThatUsesModal = props => <div>
  <ModalContext.Consumer>
    {modal => <button onClick={() => modal.open('foo')} />}
  </ModalContext.Consumer>
</div>;

<ModalContainer>
  ...deeply nested component
  <SomeComponentThatUsesModal />
  ...
</ModalContainer>
```

Here's a [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-u3g4ca).

Comment: Interesting, I havn't used decorators before. Can you explain the code a bit? I don't see how ComponentB can update state of ComponentA in your example.

Comment: I updated the answer. Hope this helps. Consider providing relevant information in the question regarding your case (A is a modal and B is modal consumer), this will help other readers to understand the case.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. I suspected there was a better solution. I know what I was doing was bad, especially because one had to know about the "singleton" concept, else it would break.