# How to show/hide spinners, snackbars, or other transient components with React Function Components

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

Is it better to render spinners, snackbars, etc. in separate DOM elements instead of adding them to the main application component tree?  In React class components, it was really easy to get a reference to the class components methods to show/hide the spinner.  With the new React Hooks function components, it's not so easy anymore.  If I put the spinner in the main component tree, could I use the new "useContext" hook to show/hide the spinner?

Below is a React Hooks global spinner using Material-UI that works but is very hacky.  How can this be made more elegant?

```
namespace Spinner {
   'use strict';

   export let show: any; // Show method ref.
   export let hide: any; // Hide method ref.

   export function Render() {
      const [visible, setVisible] = React.useState(false); //Set refresh method.

      function showIt() {
         setVisible(true); // Show spinner.
      }

      function hideIt() {
         setVisible(false); // Hide spinner.
      }

      const styles: any = createStyles({
         col1Container: { display: 'flex', alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center', flexDirection: 'column' },
      });

      return (
         <div>
            {visible && <div style={styles.col1Container}>
               <CircularProgress key={Util.uid()}
                  color='secondary'
                  size={30}
                  thickness={3.6}
               />
            </div>}

            <SetSpinnerRefs showRef={showIt} hideRef={hideIt} />
         </div>
      ); // end return.
   } // end function.

   const mounted: boolean = true;

   interface iProps {
      showRef();
      hideRef();
   }

   function SetSpinnerRefs(props: iProps) {
      // ComponentDidMount.
      React.useEffect(() => {
         Spinner.show = props.showRef;
         Spinner.hide = props.hideRef;
      }, [mounted]);

      return (<span />);
   }
} // end module.
```

Comment: *In React class components, it was really easy to get a reference to the class components methods to show/hide the spinner.* - if you have specific situation in mind, consider posting the code for 'easy' and 'hard' components. *could I use the new "useContext" hook to show/hide the spinner?* - you possibly could, or possibly couldn't. It depends.

Comment: @estus - The problem is that I don't understand how to use the "useContext" hook, so I will probably do something hacky like call ReactDOM.render on a global spinner component every time I want to show/hide it.

Comment: Posting 'incorrect' https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve would help to address it in more topical way. useContext is a replacement for context `Consumer`. If you know how to do the thing you're describe with it, please, post an example. If you know how to do this with `render`, an example would help, too. The question is too broad at this point.

Comment: @estus - I added some sample code to this post as you suggested. Is there a way to make it more elegant and less hacky?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In React class components, it was really easy to get a reference to the class components methods to show/hide the spinner

You can continue to use class components. They are not going anywhere

## The not so good way

It is actually poor practice in my opinion to use class methods to show and hide a spinner. Assuming your api looks like

```
<Spinner {ref=>this.something=ref}/>
```

And you use

```
this.something.show(); // or .hide
```

## The better way

```
<Spinner shown={state.shown}/>
```

Now you get to change `state.shown` instead of storing the ref and using `show` / `hide`.

Comment: I like to keep things simple and only have one global spinner component that I can show/hide.  I believe your example above would require me to add the "shown" state hook to every component in the application where I wanted to show/hide the spinner.  Is that correct?

Comment: I added some sample code to this post.  Is there a way to make it more elegant and less hacky?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52276827/3731501), and a solution for spinners would be the same as the one for modal windows. React hooks don't change the way it works but can make it more concise.

There is supposed to be single spinner instance in component hierarchy:

```
const SpinnerContext = React.createContext();

const SpinnerContainer = props => {
  const [visible, setVisible] = React.useState(false);

  const spinner = useMemo(() => ({
    show: () => setVisible(true),
    hide: () => setVisible(false),
  }), []);

  render() {
    return <>
      {visible && <Spinner />}
      <SpinnerContext.Provider value={spinner}>
        {props.children}
      </SpinnerContext.Provider>
    </>;
  }
}
```

Which is passed with a context:

```
const ComponentThatUsesSpinner = props => {
  const spinner = useContext(SpinnerContext);
  ...
  spinner.hide();
  ...
}

<SpinnerContainer>
  ...
  <ComponentThatUsesSpinner />
  ...
</SpinnerContainer>
```

Answer (score 0):

Although I think that Basarat's answer is the modern way of solving this problem, the below code is the way I ended up doing it.  This way I only need one line of code to build the spinner and only one line of code to show/hide it.

```
   <Spinner.Render />  {/* Build spinner component */}
   Spinner.show();     //Show spinner.

namespace Spinner {
   'use strict';
   export let show: any; //Ref to showIt method.
   export let hide: any; //Ref to hideIt method.

   export function Render() {
      const [visible, setVisible] = React.useState(false); //Set refresh method.

      function showIt() {
         setVisible(true);  //Show spinner.
      }
      function hideIt() {
         setVisible(false); //Hide spinner.
      }

      const showRef: any = React.useRef(showIt);
      const hideRef: any = React.useRef(hideIt);

      //Component did mount.
      React.useEffect(() => {
         Spinner.show = showRef.current;
         Spinner.hide = hideRef.current;
      }, []);

      const styles: any = createStyles({
         row1Container: { display: 'flex', alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' },
      });

      return (
         <div>
            {visible && <div style={styles.row1Container}>
               <CircularProgress
                  color='secondary'
                  size={30}
                  thickness={3.6}
               />
            </div>}
         </div>
      ); //end return.

   } //end function.
} //end module.
```