# how to add a function of a class into another function in a component?

Tags: reactjs

How to add RenderFunction of class of SayHello into RenderView function?

For clarity, please look at the following picture and code.

[image]

this is my code:

```
import React from 'react';

class SayHello{
  RenderFunction() {
    return (
      <p>Hello</p>
    );
  }
}


function RenderView(){
  return (
    <div>
      //I want to add RenderFunction of class of SayHello into here.
    </div>
  );
}


const DishDetail = () => {
  return(
    <div>
      <RenderView />
    </div
  );
}

export default DishDetail;
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

1. `extend` your class from `Component`.

```
export class SayHello extends Component {...}
```

2. move your `RenderFunction` into `render` as arrow function.
3. put `<SayHello  />` into methodof `RenderView`.

View the correct code below:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

export class SayHello extends Component {

    render(){

        RenderFunction = ()=> {
         return (
           <p>Hello</p>
         );
        }

        return(
           {RenderFunction()}
        );
    }

}


function RenderView(){
     return (
         <div>
             <SayHello  />
         </div>
    );
}


const DishDetail = ()=>{
     return(
         <div>
             <RenderView />
         </div
     );
}

export default DishDetail;
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe the following is what you are looking for, if I am understanding the problem you are asking. The following can be seen working here: https://codesandbox.io/s/7ykk0z90yx

Firstly we are going to be extending our react component, we can do this in two way, we can destructure from the react import like the following.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
```

Or we can just directly write it:

```
class SayHello extends React.Component
```

Secondly we need to call our `SayHello` component like we would with any other component we want to use.

Also as we are using arrow functions, I went with this approach for the `RenderView` component.

And with the above we have the following:

```
class SayHello extends Component {
  render() {
    return <p>Hello</p>;
  }
}

const RenderView = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <SayHello />
    </div>
  );
};

const DishDetail = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <RenderView />
    </div>
  );
};
```

Hope the above helps and answers your question. I have also tidied up your code. For example your original code is missing an ending `>` on it's `div`. Which obviously will not make it compile/help.

Answer (score 0):

did you try like this?

```
class SayHello{
    RenderFunction = () => {
         return (
           <p>Hello</P>
         );
    }
}

function RenderView(){
  return SayHello.RenderFunction();
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer you gave me. but it doesn't work.

Comment: What is the error? and show your full code please, because I don't see why you need `SayHello` class

Comment: well show only what is necessary, why do you need `SayHello` class ?

Comment: But my problem is exactly like the code I have put in the question.

Comment: RenderFunction is prototype method and cannot be used as static method like `SayHello.RenderFunction`.

Comment: This won't work too because you cannot access RenderFunction instance property without instantiating SayHello.

Answer (score -1):

If `RenderFunction` doesn't depend on `SayHello` instance, it shouldn't be a part of this class.

It appears like stateless function component and can be used as such because this is how composition is commonly implemented in React:

```
function RenderFunction() {
     return (
       <p>Hello</P>
     );
}

class SayHello{
  // can use <RenderFunction> too if necessary
}


function RenderView(){
    return <RenderFunction/>
}
```

In case `RenderFunction` depends on `SayHello` instance (`this.state`), this is a different problem because accessing `RenderFunction` isn't enough. On the contrary, `RenderFunction` shouldn't be additionally called because this will create additional `Modal` instances. It's existing `SayHello` component instance that needs to be accessed in other components.

`SayHello` should be a parent or a sibling to components that need to interact with a modal.

There should exist a reference to `SayHello` instance:

```
<SayHello ref={this.modalContainerRef}/>
```

Then a modal can be reached as `this.modalContainerRef.current.toggleModal()` in parent component. A callback that allows to call `toggleModal` can be passed to child components through props or context API.

Comment: But I want to add a Modal to the class that it needs to define the constructor.
How can I do this?

Comment: I see. This is actually a different problem, I'll try to explain it. SayHello looks like a component but still isn't a valid component (doesn't inherit from Component) and doesn't have `render`. Is `RenderFunction` actually supposed to be `render`? Do you need only one <Modal> instance to exist? Can you clarify this in the question?

Comment: ```RenderFunction``` will be rendered, I need only one ```<Modal>``` instance to exist.
and I have edited again ```RenderView``` function for clarity.

Comment: Then you need to do this in a different way. You can't benefit from accessing RenderFunction . I updated the answer. I believe this answer covers your case, https://stackoverflow.com/a/52276827/3731501 .